# EMAIL SPECIFIC: Display table inline

Tags: html, css, email, html-table

I'm creating a logo and nav in an email that will also stack in mobile devices.  I'm trying to get the TD with the class "navlogo" to float left and the TD with the class "main_nav" to float right in browser, yet stack in mobile.

```
    <tr>
    <td class="navlogo" width="200px" style="display:inline;">
        <table style="float:left;">
            <tr>
                <td class="ttlogo" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="200px" style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 30px; ">
                <img  width="auto"  src="http://image.jpg" alt=" Logo" border="0">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>



<tr>
    <td class="main_nav" width="400px" style="display:inline;" >
        <table style="float:right; " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="400" >
           <tr>
                <td class="nav1"  align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;  ">
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #654308;">TRAINING</a>
                </td>
    <td class="nav1"  align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;  ">
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #654308;">TRAINING</a>
                </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Since this is an email I can't use lists. I would like them side by side in browsers and stack in mobile... suggestions?

Comment: Not sure I understand.. 2 table cells in the same row would be side by side..

Comment: The TD with the class of "main Nav" and enclosing TD above it (width of 200px) are not currently side by side, they are stacked on top of each other.  Those two elements are what I need to be side by side.  There might be a way to simplify it?

Comment: Can't you simply remove the table row split? https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/yt6y24eu/

Comment: Yes I can, but that doesn't allow the image to stack on top of the links in mobile, which is the ultimate goal.  Do you know of any way that I could have the logo and links side by side in browser, yet stack on top of each other in smaller screen sizes?  Thank you

Comment: and center the logo... right now it's stacking alright but the logo isn't centered